# Formatting Selected Columns Depending Cell Value Is Odd Or Even

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have a sheet with several columns. Column A consists of numbers. Depending if the cell value in column A is even (or odd) I want to highlight several cells in that row, but not the entire row.

So far using conditionally formatting I have been able to add a formatting rule for each column I want to have highlighted. So for example if I want columns A, B and E highlighted I use three rules:

```
Formula: =ISEVEN(A1) - Highlight Format - Sheet!$A$1:$A100
Formula: =ISEVEN(A1) - Highlight Format - Sheet!$B$1:$B100
Formula: =ISEVEN(A1) - Highlight Format - Sheet!$E$1:$E100
```

...and etc for all additional columns.

But this is very cumbersome, I don't know how to make a rule to cover it all in once or even if it is possible. I'm guessing VBA might be the solution, but I'm kinda a rookie there.

Any clues on how to attack this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just fix your reference column in the formula for that (A becomes $A in this case). The ranges it applies for then can be all put in the same rule as well:

```
Formula: =ISEVEN($A1) - Highlight Format - Sheet!$A$1:$B100;Sheet!$E$1:$E100
```

So no VBA required!

Comment: This should be the easy solution indeed, BUT somehow if I do it this way only column A is formatted. I'm gonna try again, if not VBA will be my only solution, I'm afraid..

Comment: Okay, I got the adjacent columns (A & B) working, but the rest of the columns the range isn't saved somehow.

Comment: Nevermind, it's syntax! The semicolumn should be a comma. I'm sorry this questions shouldn't have needed to be asked.. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I was AFK for a while, good to see it works for you. Yeah semicolon comma etc depends on your local machine settings and can be problematic when helping someone out. Good to hear it works now. Have fun with this new knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

:) You do not need to sweat so much at all. I am not sure what your `Highlight Format` for. You can add the even, odd into the conditional formatting window/wizard text boxes and then choose the formatting colour accordingly.

Try this out:

For even:

```
=MOD(A1,2)=0
```

For odd:

```
=MOD(A1,2)>0
```

- Check the following article for better help on [Excel conditional formatting](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.CF.html#rows)
- Another article for [10 cools way to use Excel conditional formatting](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-cool-ways-to-use-excels-conditional-formatting-feature/3166)

Comment: Thanks, I saw these articles already :), but the MOD solution highlights the entire row and checks if the row number is even instead of the cell value somehow..

Comment: What you want to highlight is up to you, either a row, column or a particular range. It's the fun part, you can play around. :) If time is crucial then you may go ahead with off-the-shelf answer :D

Comment: I can see now I can choose what to highlight, there you are right :), but this formula (unless I'm doing it wrong) checks the row number as even or odd, but I need the cell value to be checked for odd or even.